# jQuery checkbox not responding when I check it

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have that function:

```
$("#tabela tr").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("zaznaczone");
    $(this).find(" :checkbox").attr("checked", "1");
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("zaznaczone");
    $(this).find(" :checkbox").attr("checked", "");
});
```

and it's fine when i click on "tr" but when i click on checkbox this line response but checkbox not. It's mean checkobx after this operation is not checked.

---

i write bottom this code:

```
$("#tabela tr :checkbox").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')==''){
        alert("000000");
    }
    else{
        alert("111111111");
    }
});
```

and what happen. When i click on empty checkbox i see alert 1111111 and before press ok on alert popup checkbox is checked. After press ok checkbox is not checked and tr get class from code up.
When i try uncheck checkbox i see this same alert 00000 and line "tr" is unset with code up

---

Your code work perfect for line and checkbox but when I try add this lines:

```
$(this).addClass("zaznaczone");
$(this).removeClass("zaznaczone");
```

then work that:
When i click on line work that what it should, but when i click on checkbox then check it addClass dont work 
All code:

```
$('#tabela tr').bind('click',function(e){
       var cb = $(this).find(':checkbox');

       if(e.target !== cb[0]){
           if(cb.is(':checked')){
               cb.removeAttr('checked');
               $(this).removeClass("zaznaczone");}

           else{
               cb.attr('checked', 'checked');
               $(this).addClass("zaznaczone");}
       }
   });
```

Comment: the right value for checked is "on"!

Comment: U have right but 1, checked work too.
Anyway it isn't solve my problem.

Comment: @jAndy - In jQuery anything that's not `~= false` works, since it's normalized :)

Comment: @Nick: I know you might even write `<input type="checkbox" checked/>`, but `w3c` says `checked` as correct value.

Comment: @jAndy - Actually it doesn't, it specifies exactly `checked` not `checked="something"`, here's the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-checked

Comment: @Nick: well yea, I was confused by the table at the very beginning. I guess 95% of all "correct" codes are not that correct :). `disabled` should also not have a value. doh! Even jQuery would break the w3c spec, you can't tell `.attr()` just to add that attribute empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to make this work with `.toggle()`, it will call `.preventDefault()` on it's own which just makes this task awesome for some reason. Maybe I'm just missing something, but the code below is just fine and works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('tr').bind('click',function(e){
       var cb = $(this).find(':checkbox');

       if(e.target !== cb[0]){
           if(cb.is(':checked'))
               cb.removeAttr('checked');
           else
               cb.attr('checked', 'checked');
       }
   });   
});
```

Comment: i will try it and back with answer

Comment: like I answer: almost look answer up